# Term for "having terms for everything"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, obscure-terms

Is there a term for the phenomenon of creating a term for every single little thing?

Comment: Obsessive, compulsive, disorder?

Comment: @WS2 Some kind of "control freakism"?...

Comment: "Denomination" is the process of naming something. I'm not sure there's really a word to describe specifically what you're looking for.

Comment: Lexirrhea? neologomania? overcoining? wordwashing? panlexogenesis? ;)

Comment: You failed to spot the deliberate mistake. I should have said 'obsessive-compulsive disorder', shouldn't I?

Comment: @WS2 Actually I noticed it.. but I didn't want to be pedantic

Comment: @d'alar'cop But it's soooooo much fun! (Being pedantic)

Comment: @Neil Very nice suggestions... I think the irony was not lost on you, sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Playing Adam** -- Taxing my memory of Genesis, wasn't one of the first tasks that Adam undertook to name all the things of the world?

Otherwise, **taxonomy** is the practice and science of classification (*i.e.* organizing the
**nomenclature**)  Clearly the goal of the science would be to name *everything* and have them be in their proper order.

[Nomenclature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomenclature) is the system of names, where as taxonomy is the application and organization of nomenclature according to scientific principles.  [Taxonomy requires scientific testing and process, whereas nomenclature is more bibliographic/legal in nature.](http://iczn.org/content/what-difference-between-nomenclature-and-taxonomy)

Comment: Can you please work "Nomenclature" into your answer David?

Comment: @d'alar'cop I have tried to clarify them for you.  They are hand and fingers to one another, if that metaphor makes sense.

Comment: I love "Playing Adam". That should be the standard term for this.  This question was sort of facetiously playing on the habits of ELU - but it was fruitful after all.

Comment: @d'alar'cop I started typing playing god, and had a flashback to religious school lo those many years ago before I lost my faith...

Comment: I see... well having faith and losing it is far worth than never having had faith at all. I hope you get plenty of philosophy - solipsistic ideas support a pretty good God concept for me.

Answer (score 1):

The term you could be looking for is [Neologism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/neologism) 2.:

> noun
>
> 1. a new word, meaning, usage, or phrase.
> 2. the introduction or use of new words or new senses of existing words.
> 3. a new doctrine, especially a new interpretation of sacred writings.
> 4. Psychiatry. a new word, often consisting of a combination of other words, that is understood only by the speaker: occurring most often in
>    the speech of schizophrenics.